Guava minSdk is not a problem unless I shadow the library
I'm working on a public library, and I need to shadow some dependencies so that consumers of the library don't get conflicts. I'm working on adding Guava to the mix. When I add Guava directly I get no problems, but when I shadow it I get a D8 error complaining about the minSdk version.
Main build.gradle.kts:
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}

android {
    namespace = "my.namespace"
    compileSdk = 34
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 16
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(path = ":Shadow-Module", configuration = "shadow"))
}

Shadow-Module's build.gradle.kts:
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

plugins {
    id("java")
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "8.1.1"
}

val shadowJar = tasks.named<ShadowJar>("shadowJar") {
    isEnableRelocation = true
    relocationPrefix = "my.namespace.shadow"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.google.guava:guava:33.1.0-android")
}

The error I get:
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26): Lmy/namespace/shadow/com/google/common/hash/Hashing$Crc32cMethodHandles;newCrc32c()Ljava/util/zip/Checksum;","sources":[{"file":"~/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/ddfd1a8942a2e6d1a88e6eb87139afdd/transformed/jetified-Shadow-Module-all.jar"}],"tool":"D8"}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':My-SDK:mergeDexAppDebugAndroidTest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':My-SDK:appDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform Shadow-Modules-all.jar (project :Shadow-Modules) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-component-attributes=ComponentSpecificParameters(minSdkVersion=16, debuggable=true, enableCoreLibraryDesugaring=false, enableGlobalSynthetics=false, enableApiModeling=false, dependenciesClassesAreInstrumented=false, asmTransformComponent=null, useJacocoTransformInstrumentation=false, enableDesugaring=true, needsClasspath=true, useFullClasspath=false, componentIfUsingFullClasspath=null), org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: ~/.gradle/caches/transforms-4/ddfd1a8942a2e6d1a88e6eb87139afdd/transformed/jetified-Shadow-Module-all.jar.
         > Error while dexing.
           Increase the minSdkVersion to 26 or above.

Increasing the minSdkVersion is not an option.
So why does D8 fail on the shadowed version of Guava but not the unshadowed version? And how do I resolve this?

You might also want to create an issue in Shadow's repo: https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow/issues

I think the problem here is not so much that we (Guava) added a usage of MethodHandle but more so that (your usage of?) the Shadow plugin is requesting the JRE flavor of Guava instead of the Android flavor. (Its request overrides your explicit request for 33.1.0-android.) Without that request, you'd be OK, as we added the usage of MethodHandle to the JRE flavor only.
I don't know enough about Gradle to find a proper solution in the 15 minutes I spent trying. My hope would be that the Shadow plugin consumes some kind of configuration that you could use to tell it to target Android rather than Java. (But maybe shadow#605 suggests that it might not? And see shadow#908.) Failing that, you may be able to override the Shadow plugin's request with your own specification of the environment attribute or resolution strategy, using one of the strategies given in our release notes for 32.1.0.
Sorry for the trouble. The automatic usage of the JRE flavor of Guava is nice for builds that are set up for it, but it's proven to be a problem for more complex builds :(
(And thanks for taking care to shade Guava when appropriate!)
